# Что такое EOF и как его использовать?

Tags: java

Вопрос в заголовке

Comment: @muhamed, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

EndOfFile буквально конец файла. Используется обычно при чтении файла, если достигнута метка EOF, то закончить чтение.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно это "END OF FILE", терминальный символ обозначающий конец файла.

Answer (score 0):

Строго говоря вот что это и не всегда при чтении файла. Также эмулирует конец ввода в консоли, при нажатии Ctrl+D
cat /usr/include/stdio.h | grep EOF
#define EOF (-1)

Answer (score -1):

Что такое EOF волнует многих начинающих в программировании... ). Вопрос есть и надо попытаться на него ответить. Написал небольшую программу на C++ в Ubuntu. Программа читала все символы в некотором заданном и изменяемом текстовом файле. Так вот, оказалось, что в конце файла обязательно присутствует три последовательных перевода строки.... \n\n\n! Всегда в текстовом файле! Конечно же эту последовательность можно очень просто интерпретировать как EOF. Пожалуйста, вот такое есть мнение.

Comment: Откуда у вас 3 ньюлайна не знаю, но в целом **абсолютно не верно**. Правильный ответ -- никаких символов, обозначающих EOF в файле нет. Этот символ (32-бит число (обычно -1, т.е. все биты установлены в 1)) отличается от всех остальных (у них значимые всегда только младшие 8 бит) и в случае чтния файла формируется в библиотеке io, когда используемый ей для чтения файла системный вызов read возвращает -1 (вместо прочитанного им из файла количества байт)